# Getting a floating point exception error while doing text frequency analysis?

Tags: c++, arrays, hash

So for a school project, we are being asked to do a word frequency analysis of a text file using dictionaries and bucket hashing. The output should be something like this:

```
$ ./stats < jabberwocky.txt
READING text from STDIN. Hit ctrl-d when done entering text.
DONE.
HERE are the word statistics of that text:

There are 94 distinct words used in that text.

The top 10 ranked words (with their frequencies) are:
1. the:19, 2. and:14, 3. !:11, 4. he:7, 5. in:6, 6. .:5, 7. 
through:3, 8. my:3, 9. jabberwock:3, 10. went:2

Among its 94 words, 57 of them appear exactly once.
```

Most of the code has been written for us, but there are four functions we need to complete to get this working:

`increment(dict D, std::str w)` which will increment the count of a word or add a new entry in the dictionary if it isn't there,

`getCount(dict D, std::str w)` which fetches the count of a word or returns 0,

`dumpAndDestroy(dict D)` which dumps the words and counts of those words into a new array by decreasing order of count and deletes D's buckets off the heap, and returns the pointer to that array,

`rehash(dict D, std::str w)` which rehashes the function when needed.

The structs used are here for reference:

```
  // entry
  //
  // A linked list node for word/count entries in the dictionary.
  //
struct entry {

    std::string word;  // The word that serves as the key for this entry.

    int count;         // The integer count associated with that word.

    struct entry* next;
  };

  // bucket
  //
  // A bucket serving as the collection of entries that map to a
  // certain location within a bucket hash table.
  //
  struct bucket {

    entry* first;  // It's just a pointer to the first entry in the
           // bucket list.
  };

  // dict
  //
  // The unordered dictionary of word/count entries, organized as a
  // bucket hash table.
  //
  struct dict {

    bucket* buckets;   // An array of buckets, indexed by the hash function.

    int numIncrements; // Total count over all entries. Number of `increment` calls.

    int numBuckets;    // The array is indexed from 0 to numBuckets.

    int numEntries;    // The total number of entries in the whole
               // dictionary, distributed amongst its buckets.

    int loadFactor;    // The threshold maximum average size of the
               // buckets. When numEntries/numBuckets exceeds
               // this loadFactor, the table gets rehashed.
  };
```

I've written these functions, but when I try to run it with a text file, I get a Floating point exception error. I've emailed my professor for help, but he hasn't replied. This project is due very soon, so help would be much appreciated! My written functions for these are as below:

```
int getCount(dict* D, std::string w) {
    int stringCount;
    int countHash = hashValue(w, numKeys(D));
      bucket correctList = D->buckets[countHash];
      entry* current = correctList.first;
      while (current != nullptr && current->word < w) {
        if (current->word == w) {
          stringCount = current->count;
        }
        current = current->next;
      }
    std::cout << "getCount working" << std::endl;
    return stringCount;
  }
```

```
void rehash(dict* D) {
    // UNIMPLEMENTED
    int newSize = (D->numBuckets * 2) + 1;
    bucket** newArray = new bucket*[newSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < D->numBuckets; i++) {
        entry *n = D->buckets->first;
        while (n != nullptr) {
            entry *tmp = n;
            n = n->next;
            int newHashValue = hashValue(tmp->word, newSize);
            newArray[newHashValue]->first = tmp;
        }
    }
    delete [] D->buckets;
    D->buckets = *newArray;
    std::cout << "rehash working" << std::endl;
    return;
```

```
void increment(dict* D, std::string w) {
    // UNIMPLEMENTED
    int incrementHash = hashValue(w, numKeys(D));
    entry* current = D->buckets[incrementHash].first;
    if (current == nullptr) {
      int originalLF = D->loadFactor;
      if ((D->numEntries + 1)/(D->numBuckets) > originalLF) {
        rehash(D);
        int incrementHash = hashValue(w, numKeys(D));
        }
      D->buckets[incrementHash].first->word = w;
      D->buckets[incrementHash].first->count++;

    }
    while (current != nullptr && current->word < w) {
      entry* follow = current;
      current = current->next;
      if (current->word == w) {
        current->count++;
      }
    }
    std::cout << "increment working" << std::endl;
    D->numIncrements++;
  }
```

```
entry* dumpAndDestroy(dict* D) {
    // UNIMPLEMENTED
    entry* es = new entry[D->numEntries];
    for (int i = 0; i < D->numEntries; i++) {
      es[i].word = "foo";
      es[i].count = 0;
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < D->numBuckets; j++) {
      entry* current = D->buckets[j].first;
      while (current != nullptr) {
        es[j].word = current->word;
        es[j].count = current->count;
        current = current->next;
      }
    }
    delete [] D->buckets;
    std::cout << "dumpAndDestroy working" << std::endl;
    return es;
```

Comment: A debugger will point you directly at the problem. Build your code with debugging turned on, then run it in the debugger. When it crashes the debugger should show you the line of code and the variable values.

Comment: Unfortunately my personal laptop is broken so I have to use a school computer with nothing installed, so I have to use repl.it, which doesn't have a C++ debugger. I'll see if I can find anything though.

Comment: Actually I found a debugger, and it says I have a segmentation fault in the increment function, when D->buckets[incrementHash].first->word = w is executed.

Comment: If it is a segmentation fault then one of those pointers involved is not correct, or your `incrementHash` is out of bounds for `buckets`.

Comment: Pointers there could be `D`, `buckets`, `first`

Answer (score 0):

A floating-point exception is usually caused by the code attempting to divide-by-zero (or attempting to modulo-by-zero, which implicitly causes a divide-by-zero).  With that in mind, I suspect this line is the locus of your problem:

```
if ((D->numEntries + 1)/(D->numBuckets) > originalLF) {
```

Note that if `D->numBuckets` is equal to zero, this line will do a divide-by-zero.  I suggest temporarily inserting a line like like

```
std::cout << "about to divide by " << D->numBuckets << std::endl;
```

just before that line, and then re-running your program; that will make the problem apparent, assuming it is the problem.  The solution, of course, is to make sure your code doesn't divide-by-zero (i.e. by setting `D->numBuckets` to the appropriate value, or alternatively by checking to see if it is zero before trying to use it is a divisor)

Comment: I tried that, but that doesn't seem to be it. I'll keep on looking. Thanks for the help!